# Trying to get spark streaming to read data stream from website, what is the socket?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I am trying to get this data http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps into spark stream

They are JSON objects, I know the lines will be strings, I just want it to work before I try JSON.

I am not sure what to put as the port, I assume that is the problem.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Spark Streaming");

JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1));

JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.socketTextStream("http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps", 80);


lines.print();

jssc.start();
jssc.awaitTermination();
```

Here is my error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
```

Comment: `UnknownHostException: Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.` So can you resolve the DNS from you spark nodes?

Comment: Interesting, I don't know how spark handles DNS. Is there a way I can find the IP address of that site?

Comment: Your Spark worked nodes may not have set DNS servers correctly or can't access internet at all. Try to check it.

Comment: Do you know how to setup DNS for spark?

Comment: Nevermind, it turns out that spark socketTextStream doesn't work with website URL, I need to create my own streaming receiver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The socketTextStream isn't designed to work as an http client. As you noticed, you will need to create a custom receiver, one potential place to start is based on the receiver created as part of the meetup streaming data source (see https://github.com/actions/meetup-stream/blob/master/src/main/scala/receiver/MeetupReceiver.scala ).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom *UrlReceiver* which follows spark documentation on custom receivers:

```scala
class UrlReceiver(urlStr: String) extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) with Logging {

  override def onStart() = {
    new Thread("Url Receiver") {
      override def run() = {
        val urlConnection: URLConnection = new URL(urlStr).openConnection
        val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream)
        )
        var msg = bufferedReader.readLine
        while (msg != null) {
          if (!msg.isEmpty) {
            store(msg)
          }
          msg = bufferedReader.readLine
        }
        bufferedReader.close()
      }
    }.start()
  }

  override def onStop() = {
    // nothing to do
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```scala
val lines = sc.receiverStream(new UrlReceiver("http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps"))
```