# How to retrieve data with spark streaming from a website?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I would like to retrieve data in streaming from a website using Spark streaming. I think that I have to use custom receivers. So, I tried this :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object StreamingMain {

 val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
 val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
 val lines = ssc.receiverStream(new UrlReceiver("http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps"))
 
 println("lines value" +  lines.print())
 
 val words: DStream[String] = lines.flatMap(_.split(","))
}


import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.BufferedReader

import java.net.{URL, URLConnection}

import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging

 class UrlReceiver(urlStr: String) extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)   with Logging {

override def onStart() = {
    new Thread("Url Receiver") {
        override def run() = {
            val urlConnection: URLConnection = new URL(urlStr).openConnection
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0")
            println(urlConnection)
            val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream)
            )
            var msg = bufferedReader.readLine
            while (msg != null) {
                if (!msg.isEmpty) {
                    store(msg)
                    println("msg" + msg)
                }
                msg = bufferedReader.readLine
            }
            bufferedReader.close()
        }
    }.start()
}

override def onStop() = {

   }
}
```

I have the following result on the console with no data:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1602750320000 ms
-------------------------------------------
```

I would like to retrieve data in streaming from the website. As soon as a new data is  on the website, I would like to track it. The streaming application should be always running (it should stop if I or the user decide to stop the application)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get spark streaming to read data stream from website, what is the socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672898/trying-to-get-spark-streaming-to-read-data-stream-from-website-what-is-the-sock)

Comment: I tried to follow the link you shared but it does not work. That's why I ask the question.